# the best calling web api in webform application asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, http

i created a web api like this
[image]

and the controller :

```
 public tbl_Users   Get(int  id)
    {
        DocManagerEntities1 db = new DocManagerEntities1();
        var data = from item in db.tbl_Users
                   where item.U_ID == id
                   select item;
        return data.FirstOrDefault();
    }
```

now i want to call this api in asp.net c# webform application 
whats the best way to do this ? 
(i dont want do this with Jquery)
thanks alot

Comment: then how to call api?

Comment: @syedmhamudulhasanakash call with http client

Answer (score 0):

Here is my Api implementation

Models

```
public class Cars
    {
        public string carName;
        public string carRating;
        public string carYear;
    }
```

my api controller

```
public class DefaultController : ApiController
    {
        public HttpResponseMessage GetCarses()
        {
            List<Cars> carList = new List<Cars>();
            carList.Add(new Cars
            {
                carName = "a",
                carRating = "b",
                carYear = "c"
            });
            carList.Add(new Cars
            {
                carName = "d",
                carRating = "e",
                carYear = "f"
            });
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, carList); ;
        } 
    }
```

and my response from HttpClient

```
  String jsonData;
            string url =
                String.Format(
                    @" http://localhost:37266/api/Default/GetCars");

            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
            {

                using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
                {
                    jsonData = reader.ReadToEnd();
                }

                //Console.WriteLine(jsonData);
            }
            var cars = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<List<Cars>>(jsonData);
            var ss = cars;
```

Dont forget to add

```
 protected void Application_Start()
        {
            //add this line if not 
            GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
            ...
        }
```