# consume a web api from server side with datatable as parameter in asp.net web forms

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

Hello I have a API method build in framework 4 which returns string type of data

```
[HttpPost]
        public string ValidateData(DataTable dt)
        {
            return _repository.ValidateAllData(dt);
        }
```

Now I want to consume this API method in my asp.net application from server side.
Now how do i consume this method with datatable as parameter ?

Comment: Have a look at this question, I think it is what you need: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34626483/how-to-pass-datatable-via-frombody-to-web-api-post-method-c

Comment: Use Id to pass and get datatable from  DB

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40048476/4611027

Answer (score 0):

```
HttpClient cons = new HttpClient();
cons.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:7967/");
cons.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
cons.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
HttpResponseMessage res =  await cons.PostAsJsonAsync("api/revise", data);
```

In above code you need to pass datatable as data parameter to make it working.